# keyup backspace creates lag issues when removing string from input field

Tags: jquery

Not sure whats causing my script to lag when I press the backspace key. The script highlights a match, but when the backspace key is hit it removes the match, but it creates a lag:

```
$input.keyup("input", function(e) {
if (e.keyCode === 8) {
  $content.unmark();
  $(".kwt-count").html("");
}

});
```

Here is the link to a codepen I've created. Any help is appreciated: [add and remove highlight](https://codepen.io/dude12go8/pen/PoYbdXd)

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean with a lag. When I enter "dolor" and press the return key, it highlights the matches. When I press backspace the matches are un-highlighted immediately.

Comment: it freezes up. When you continue to keep pressing the backspace key you will notice that it freezes up. When you delete up to the "dol" you will notice the lag

Comment: When I enter a long sentence and press backspace continuously the cursor doesn't freeze even the slightest. When I stop midway through a sentence (after pressing backspace continuously) and press return, the matches are highlighted immediately.

Comment: right I tried that, but still not sure why it causes it to move slowly each time its pressed.

Comment: What browser were you using?

Comment: I tested it in both Chrome and Firefox. I had a quick look at your code and I can't spot anything which might cause a delay. The only thing i could possibly suggest is to use vanilla JavaScript as opposed to JQuery, but I highly doubt that would be the issue (if there's one at all) and wouldn't give a noticeable performance benefit.